# how to convert docx file having images into pdf using aspose in android?

Tags: android, aspose

I have tried to convert ".docx" file having images but it always give no class found error for "java.awt.imagebuffer" class

Comment: I just tested the conversion on a device and emulator, the images are present in the output pdf file. Are you getting this error on compile time or when you run the program?

Comment: i am getting this error when i run the program@SaqibRazzaq

Answer (score 0):

Try this project, it converts a DOCX file from sd card to PDF.

Download location: [Google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6S7uu28AdY0Q2hsM0k5cmRQVms&authuser=1)

Steps to run this sample

1. Unzip the file and open it in Android Studio.
2. Run an emulator. Open DDMS by choosing Tools - Android - Android Device Monitor from the menu
3. Place the word document (sample.docx) in sdcard/Download folder.
4. Run the project, it should create the PDF.

Try this procedure with your DOCX file. If it does not work, please post the sample document and code in [Aspose forums](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx).

[image: Place file]

**To Fix Fonts/Blocks Issue**
The android device or emulator may not have the fonts that are used in the Word document. For example, Calibiri is the default font in Office 2010 and it is not available in Android.

In this case, you need to

1. Copy the font files from Windows system (c:\Windows \Fonts) to the Android device/emulator (storage/sdcard/Download). See screenshot
2. In the program, set the path of the folder where you copied the fonts. See the code below.

   Document doc = new Document(src);

   ArrayList fontSources = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(FontSettings.getFontsSources()));
   FolderFontSource folderFontSource = new FolderFontSource(dataDir, true);
   fontSources.add(folderFontSource);
   FontSourceBase[] updatedFontSources = (FontSourceBase[])fontSources.toArray(new FontSourceBase[fontSources.size()]);
   FontSettings.setFontsSources(updatedFontSources);

   doc.save(dst);

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code....It is creating the pdf file,but text is not showing...insted of text it is showing boxes.....can u check this please.

Comment: It is due to the missing fonts issue, I have updated the answer to handle fonts